# Yammer Embed login Popup Not Working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, yammer

I am using yammer embed code to show the yammer embed feeds.

The login pop up is working fine in Firefox and Chrome but when I tested my site in IE 11, when I click on the login pop up a dialog box is coming like:

> The webpage you are viewing is trying to close the tab? Do you want to close the tab?

When I click on the "Yes" dialog box disappears and nothing happens. When I add `//*.yammer.com` and `//*.assets.yammer.com` in the trusted sites, the problem is solved.

But is there any other option to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't another option. This is happening due to the design of Internet Explorer, and the interactions across domains that are required to complete authentication to Yammer.

You only had to add the domains you listed, but others using Yammer Embed may need to add [additional domains](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-365-URLs-and-IP-address-ranges-8548a211-3fe7-47cb-abb1-355ea5aa88a2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1#bkmk_yammer) that are listed in the FQDN documentation. The most thorough method for resolution of this type of problem is to analyze the actual domains used for requests and include those in mutually agreeable zones.

It's worth pointing out that adding domains to Trusted Sites is not completely correct. Adding the domains used to mutually agreeable domains is more technically correct, which can mean that you need to remove domains from the Intranet Zone to get Embed working correctly. Depending on group policy you may have trouble doing this unless you work closely with the IT administrators in an organization. [IE Zone Analyzer](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fdcc/2011/09/22/iezoneanalyzer-v3-5-with-zone-map-viewer/) is a tool that can help [understand your zone configuration](http://www.brianlyttle.com/2013/04/debugging-problems-with-ie-zones/).